# How to disable auto-link in cell output in JupyterLab Notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I am using JupyterLab (2.1.3) and I have some cells printing URIs in the form of strings like

```
print('<http://www.wikidata.org/prop/direct/P31>')
```

but the output has active the auto-link feature so the output is

```
<http://www.wikidata.org/prop/direct/P31&gt;
```

How can I disable this?

**EDIT**
The behaviour is fixed in the latest `3.X` but still the question is how to disable this behaviour.

Comment: Which version of JupyterLab do you use? It works perfectly well for me in 3.0.12.

Comment: I am using 2.13 but still, how do I disable it?

Comment: There was never 2.13 release of JupyterLab. Did you mean 2.1.3 or 1.2.13? From this issue it seems like it was fixed in 2.2.0: https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/8376. Either way, I strongly recommend upgrading. I think there is no option to disable autolink, but you could certainly propose it in the GitHub repository and send a PR to implement a switch.

Comment: `2.1.3` right. So it is currently impossible to disable?